# iOS Newstand app issue hosting

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, hosting, newsstand-kit

I am working on a Newsstand app and I am looking for some clarifications regarding the issue hosting. For this project magazine issues will be stored as an archive of JSON files, images and videos. 
Does this kind of content can be stored on Apple servers or do I have to host this on my own server and implement a proper backend for this?

Answer (score 0):

Apple **does not** host your content, you have to host content on your own server and implement a proper backend.

- Get the list of issues available with their info (name, short description, download link for content etc.,)
- Display them according to your design.
- Download the corresponding resources of each issue when user taps download using Newsstand kit framework.
- Archiving all the resources into one zip file and downloading that file is recommended. Later you can unzip and access the contents. OfCourse if the issue is a paid one, verify the subscription status and then download.

Hope this is helpful.